# User defined objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

ok, so below is the code that creates a user defined object with two properties. Runs fine but the values gets over-written. How do i display all the values that the user enters in the object "objOrg"

```
const size = Number(prompt("Enter the number of employees to be registered"));
const orgObj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i<=size; i++){
        Object.defineProperties(orgObj, {
              empName: {
                 value: prompt("Enter employee name"),
                 writable: true
        },
              empId: {
                 value: prompt("Enter employee id"),
                 writable: true
        }
    })

}
console.log(orgObj);
```

Comment: How do you want them to display? Display as they type or display after all the data has been entered? Also please share the Html where you want to display. You would also need to store the data in an array of Objects to view all of them

Comment: You need to move const orgObj = {}; inside the for loop and push it to array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a class Employee to achieve this

```js
const size = Number(prompt("Enter the number of employees to be registered"));

class Employee {
  constructor(name, id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
  }
}

let employees = [];

for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    let value = prompt("Enter employee name");
    let id = prompt("Enter employee ID");
    employees[i] = new Employee(value, id);
    console.log(employees[i]);
}

console.log(employees);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want to create an array of orgs and add each one to it?

```js
const size = Number(prompt("Enter the number of employees to be registered"));
const orgs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < size; i++){
    const orgObj = {};
    Object.defineProperties(orgObj, {
        empName: {
            value: prompt("Enter employee name"),
            writable: true,
            enumerable: true
        },
        empId: {
            value: prompt("Enter employee id"),
            writable: true,
            enumerable: true
        }
    });
    orgs.push(orgObj);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(orgs));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const size = Number(prompt("Enter the number of employees to be registered"));
const orgObj = {};
    for (let i = 1; i<=size; i++){
        Object.defineProperties(orgObj, {
              ['empName'+i]: {
                 value: prompt("Enter employee name"),
                 writable: true,
                 enumerable:true,
        },
              ['empId'+i]: {
                 value: prompt("Enter employee id"),
                 writable: true,
                   enumerable:true,
        }
    })

}
console.log(orgObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could push the objects to an array

```js
const size = Number(prompt("Enter the number of employees to be registered"));
const arr=[]
const orgObj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i<=size; i++){
        Object.defineProperties(orgObj, {
              empName: {
                 value: prompt("Enter employee name"),
                 writable: true
        },
              empId: {
                 value: prompt("Enter employee id"),
                 writable: true
        }
    })
arr.push(orgObj)
}
console.log(arr);
```